# OpenCore - Dell 5577 - Can't get battery to work Hackintosh

Tags: hackintosh, opencore

I finally installed Hackintosh without getting scared, as I found out that OpenCore was the easiest way.
Got to install on my Dell 5577, Audio/Bluetooth/Wifi/Hi-Dpi all things are finally working but the only thing that is bothering me is the battery percentage.
As I tried RehabMan's battery patch but it is only available for Dell Inspiron 15 7xxx series but then my laptop is stuck 6% there's no actual solution anywhere.
 
Can anyone please guide me ?

[This is the repo](https://github.com/Nerdion/Hackintosh_OpenCore)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same Laptop
https://github.com/wgggSg/OpenCore-For-DELL-5577

this repo has working opencore config

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was really looking for answers everywhere, no one replied.